# How to enable SSL support on DISQUS?

Tags: wordpress, https, disqus

How do I enable HTTPS/SSL support for DISQUS?

I'm aware that it has been implemented, but I'm unable to find out how to enable it in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

We updated the [Disqus plugin for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/) in version 2.71 ([change log](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/other_notes/)) to support SSL. There's nothing you need to do other than load your itself via SSL — if the page is loaded via HTTPS, Disqus will load via HTTPS. Specifically, the embed (embed.js) and the comment counts on your site's front page (count.js) will load via HTTPS, which redirects them to be called via securecdn.disqus.com instead of mediacdn.disqus.com.

Note that it may take up to 24 hours for this to take effect on your site once you first transition to calling pages via HTTPS. Also, because of this caching, keep in mind that each time Disqus is called via HTTP instead of HTTPS this same wait may occur. If that's not desirable we'd recommend appending ?https to the end of the embed.js and count.js calls in the plugin which will force them to be loaded via HTTPS.

Comment: I was having problems with disqus and ssl and IE8 on version 2.72, i upgraded to 2.73 and the problems are gone.